# Pass column names as strings to group_by and summarize

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize, rlang, quosure

With dplyr starting version 0.7 the methods ending with underscore such as summarize_ group_by_ are deprecated since we are supposed to use quosures.

See:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

I am trying to implement the following example using quo and !!

Working example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), y=c(1,1,2,2,3,3), z = 1:6)

lFG <- df %>% 
   group_by( x,y) 
lFG %>% summarize( min(z))
```

However, in the case, I need to implement the columns to group by and summarize are specified as strings.

```
cols2group <- c("x","y")
col2summarize <- "z"
```

How can I get the same example as above working?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this you can now use `_at` versions of the verbs

```
df %>%  
  group_by_at(cols2group) %>% 
  summarize_at(.vars = col2summarize, .funs = min)
```

**Edit (2021-06-09):**

Please see Ronak Shah's answer, using

```
mutate(across(all_of(cols2summarize), min))
```

Now the preferred option

Answer (score 12):

From `dplyr` 1.0.0 you can use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)

cols2group <- c("x","y")
col2summarize <- "z"

df %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(cols2group))) %>%
  summarise(across(all_of(col2summarize), min)) %>%
  ungroup

#   x       y     z
#  <chr> <dbl> <int>
#1 a         1     1
#2 a         2     3
#3 b         2     4
#4 b         3     5
```

Comment: Why do you need the `all_of` inside the across? I just used it without and it works as expected. And it works for Spark!

Comment: It will work as expected but it will give you a warning (once per session) `Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.ℹ Use \`all_of(cols2group)\` instead of \`cols2group\` to silence this message.`

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use non-standard evaluation (NSE), and have R interpret the string as quoted names of objects:

```
cols2group <- c("x","y")
col2summarize <- "z"

df %>%  
  group_by(!!rlang::sym(cols2group)) %>% 
  summarize(min(!!rlang::sym(col2summarize)))
```

The `rlang::sym()` function takes the strings and turns them into quotes, which are in turn unquoted by `!!` and used as names in the context of `df` where they refer to the relevant columns. There's different ways of doing the same thing, as always, and this is the shorthand I tend to use!

Answer (score 1):

See ?dplyr::across for the updated way to do this since group_by_at and summarize_at are now Superseded